# Trouble with Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm creating a custom post type with taxonomies in WordPress 4.7.3, but for some reason the taxonomy pages aren't working properly. My custom post type is "events", but the archive-events.php template file isn't working when visiting "mysite.com/events/event-category" or when visiting "mysite.com/events"

Below is my code from functions.php, what am I doing wrong here??? lol

```
                add_action( 'init', 'register_events', 20 );
            function register_events() {
                $labels = array(
                    'name' => _x( 'All Events', 'events','sonal' ),
                    'singular_name' => _x( 'Event', 'events', 'sonal' ),
                    'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'events', 'sonal' ),
                    'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Event', 'events', 'sonal' ),
                    'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Event', 'events', 'sonal' ),
                    'new_item' => _x( 'New Event', 'events', 'sonal' ),
                    'view_item' => _x( 'View Event', 'events', 'sonal' ),
                    'search_items' => _x( 'Search Events', 'events', 'sonal' ),
                    'not_found' => _x( 'No Events found...', 'events', 'sonal' ),
                    'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No Events found in Trash', 'events', 'sonal' ),
                    'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Event:', 'events', 'sonal' ),
                    'menu_name' => _x( 'Events', 'events', 'sonal' ),
                );

                $args = array(
                    'labels' => __( $labels, 'local' ),
                    'hierarchical' => true,
                    'description' => 'events',
                    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'revisions' ),
                    'taxonomies' => array( 'events_category'),
                    'show_ui' => true,
                    'show_in_menu' => true,
                    'menu_position' => 5,
                    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-tickets-alt',
                    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                    'publicly_queryable' => true,
                    'exclude_from_search' => false,
                    'query_var' => true,
                    'can_export' => true,
                    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'events/%events_category%','with_front' => FALSE),
                    'public' => true,
                    'has_archive' => 'events_category',
                    'capability_type' => 'post'
                );  
                register_post_type( 'events', $args );
            }  
            //Create Taxonomies (Categories)
            add_action( 'init', 'create_events_taxonomies', 20 );
            function create_events_taxonomies() {
                $labels = array(
                    'name'              => _x( 'Event Categories', 'taxonomy general name', 'sonal' ),
                    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Event Category', 'taxonomy singular name', 'sonal' ),
                    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Event Categories', 'sonal' ),
                    'all_items'         => __( 'All Event Categories', 'sonal' ),
                    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Event Category', 'sonal' ),
                    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Event Category:', 'sonal' ),
                    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Event Category', 'sonal' ),
                    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Event Category', 'sonal' ),
                    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Event Category', 'sonal' ),
                    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Event Category Name', 'sonal' ),
                    'menu_name'         => __( 'Event Categories', 'sonal' ),
                );

                $args = array(
                    'hierarchical'      => true,
                    'labels'            => $labels,
                    'show_ui'           => true,
                    'show_admin_column' => true,
                    'query_var'         => true,
                    'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'events', 'with_front' => false ),
                );

                register_taxonomy( 'events_category', array( 'events' ), $args );
            }
            //Set Permalinks
            function wpa_events_permalinks( $post_link, $post ){
                if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'events' ){
                    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'events_category' );
                    if( $terms ){
                        return str_replace( '%events_category%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
                    }
                }
                return $post_link;
            }
            add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpa_events_permalinks', 1, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the /%events_category% from the rewrite argument of the events custom post type

Before:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'events/%events_category%','with_front' => FALSE),
```

After:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'events','with_front' => FALSE),
```

Again in the args of the events custom post type, set "has_archive" to true

Before

```
'has_archive' => 'events_category',
```

After:

```
'has_archive' => true,
```

Refresh permalink in Setting -> permalinks
Be sure that you chose custom structure with

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

Then go to

```
yoursite.com/events/
```

the archive-events.php file should work